# Convert templates from Word 2003 to Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

What should I consider when converting/re-creating templates from Word 2003 to Word 2010?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand the XML based formatting that Office 2010 uses is 100% backward compatible with the Office 2003 format.

This means that you should be able to open the Office 2003 template in Office 2010 and simply "Save As Word Template *.dotx" and it will (should) preserve your full formatting.

Also, when you save "Compatibility-Mode" documents into the new Office 2010 format, if any changes are going to be made to your document, Word will pop up with a prompt detailing what changes need to be done.

Good luck!!